# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{sin(5n)}{5^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have to find if this series is convergent or divergent.

This is the series:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{sin(5n)}{5^n}}$

I can't use the Ratio Test, and I don't know what to do with the sine in the numerator. Could someone give me a tip to get started?

Comment: Show it converges absolutely. Note $|\sin(5n)|\le 1$.

Comment: So, |sin(5n)|<=1 and 5^n is increasing, so it is convergent by the Alternating Series Test? Would that work?

Comment: No. You could use the Comparison Test. $\sum 1/5^n$ is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. I was thinking about the stuff I've learned in the last few weeks, and forgot about that.

Comment: If you write  terms of the sequence $ \ a_n \ = \ \sin (5n) \ $ , with $ \ 5n \  $ being an angle in radians, you'll find it isn't an _alternating_ sequence. That's why the AST won't help you here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the alternating series test for

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\sin(5n)}{5^n}} $$

Since $|\sin(5n)| \leq 1$ and noting that $$\left|\frac{\sin(5n)}{5^n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{5^n}$$

it will easily follow that the series converges *absolutely*.

Comment: Indeed so....+1

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Since $|\sin \alpha| \leq 1 $  for any $\alpha$, then

$$ \frac{| \sin (5n)| }{|5^n|} \leq \frac{1}{5^n} $$

Now, Use geometric series and compare.

Comment: You must use an absolute value notation for that $\;\sin 5n\;$, otherwise the comparison test isn't appliable here...

Comment: fixed it. sorrry Don!

Comment: (Don!): don't apologize...unless you're caught kissing the wrong girl/guy *in front* of the wrong guy/girl . +1